# git error “unable to write sha1 filename … Permission denied”

Tags: git

I am using git on windows. This is what I did: doing development on machine M1, created bare repository on USB drive M2 to backup the repository on M1. I did backups using this command (from git bash on M1):

```
git push --mirror "f:\repo"
```

Worked without any issues.
Then I bought a new machine M3. I cloned the repository from M2 to M3:

```
git clone "f:\repo" .
```

Made some checkins to the repo in M3. Then I did  (from git bash on machine M3)

```
git push --mirror "f:\repo"
```

I get this error:
unable to write sha1 filename … Permission denied
How can I fix this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3829498/119790

Comment: Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829498/git-over-samba-unable-to-write-sha1-filename-permission-denied/6777323#6777323

Comment: @morpheus you need to mark an answer here.

Comment: @jcollum - i could not fix my problem using answer by VonC. i never tried the answer by dulon. i am not debugging this issue any more.

Comment: @morpheus yeah i've been in that situation before, I usually mark the one with the most upvotes as the answer

Comment: @jcollum - there are pros and cons to it. When I see an answer marked as answer, I understand this has solved OP's question. Therefore, if I am unable to solve the problem with provided answer, I get really puzzled and nervous. So that is why I haven't marked it as answer. People upvote if answer is helpful - an upvote doesn't mean this answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Bit late but none of these worked for me. I had to run `sudo git gc` in the remote repository and that somehow fixed all my problems.

After that I pushed again and it worked

Comment: Thanks -- in addition to this I also had to chown andy:andy in the .git folder, I had changed some permission settings, but that error didn't come up until I ran this.

Comment: `git gc` on the bare repository site solved the problem for me, as well.

Answer (score 8):

Even if it is about a different context (git+ssh), check the ACL associated with your repo.
See for instance this [blog post](http://slacy.com/blog/2009/09/git-error-unable-to-write-sha1-filename-permission-denied/).

As suggested in the SO question "[Git pull error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685319/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename/2912558#2912558)" (which has other interesting suggestions as well), try redoing your bare repo, this time with the config:

```
git config core.sharedRepository true
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this error because of permissions on distant respository. In my case it was the ssh user which was the wrong one for rights.

Answer (score 1):

My particular error messages:

```
error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/ee/7ed0ef8db273d8d0acef46f3cc8ad0ae140d50: Permission denied
```

I just fixed my problem.  It turned out to be the repository issue.
In the /GIT/HOME/projectdir/objects/

doing ls you should see a lots of directories with 2 letters:

```
00  0a  14  1e  28  32  3c  46  50  5a  64  6e  78  82  8c  96  a0  aa  b4  be  c8  d2  dc  e6  f0  fa
01  0b  15  1f  29  33  3d  47  51  5b  65  6f  79  83  8d  97  a1  ab  b5  bf  c9  d3  dd  e7  f1  fb
02  0c  16  20  2a  34  3e  48  52  5c  66  70  7a  84  8e  98  a2  ac  b6  c0  ca  d4  de  e8  f2  fc
03  0d  17  21  2b  35  3f  49  53  5d  67  71  7b  85  8f  99  a3  ad  b7  c1  cb  d5  df  e9  f3  fd
04  0e  18  22  2c  36  40  4a  54  5e  68  72  7c  86  90  9a  a4  ae  b8  ... (many others removed) info pack
```

Here I just list a few for example (ee that trigger the error message is one of them).  ls -l will show some directories got -r read only permission. using the git account do chmod -R +w on those directories missing the w label solved my problem.  In my case several directories including 'ee' missed the write permission.

Answer (score 0):

I too get the same error but usually when doing a "git pull" using bash on windows machine.

For me, its related to some other application (usually a virus checker in my case) causing conflicts by holding onto the .git directory.

I can usually do "git pull" a few more times and it will eventually work (after failing with same permission denied error on a different hash value) or if I'm feeling in a hurry, I would stop my virus checker, do the git pull (which would work successfully first time without the permission error) and then very quickly switch the virus checker back on again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and was able to fix it by going to the `C:\Program Files\Git` then right click on `git-bash.exe` -> properties -> Compatibility -> Run this program as an Administrator.

Comment: Catch same error when try to commit at local repo. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue when a colleague did not have the correct **umask** setting in his **.bashrc** that caused any files he committed to be set as read only for the rest of us trying to write changes to that same file in the git repo.

You can setup umask in /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile file for all users. By default most Linux distro set it to 0022 (022) or 0002 (002). Open /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc file, enter:

```
# vi /etc/profile
```

OR

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
```

Append/modify following line to setup a new umask:

```
umask 022
```

Save and close the file. Changes will take effect after next login. All UNIX users can override the system umask defaults in their /etc/profile file, ~/.profile (Korn / Bourne shell) ~/.cshrc file (C shells), ~/.bash_profile (Bash shell) or ~/.login file (defines the user’s environment at login).

Here is a [link explaining umask permissions](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17870811)

Comment: Great thanks for the tip. It was my first comment ever on this website, I will learn and improve.

Comment: Edited and added some instructions as part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue during 2 days and i finally figured out a way to solve it. The error occurs because the branch (in the remote repository) you actually wanna push into is currently checked out. When applying the `--mirror` or `--all` option, at least a branch is checked out, therefore the permission denied.

So just switch to another branch on the remote and apply the `push` locally and this time it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when your remote resides on the same machine and is owned by *root*, e. g.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  /root/git/project.git (fetch)
origin  /root/git/project.git (push)
```

In this case you either need to push as *root* or adjust the permissions of remote to allow different users to push.