# Git Push Error Not all refs have been pushed

Tags: git, git-push

I'm trying to push the changes from my development clone to my origin repository
I've tried cleaning the origin and fetching then pushing...none of which has worked.

**The errors:**

[image: Smartgit output]

my **.git config** looks like:

```
[core]
      repositoryformatversion = 0
      filemode = false
      bare = false
      logallrefupdates = true
      symlinks = false
      ignorecase = true
      hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
      url = Z:\\_sandbox\\jacqui\\GitTest
[branch "HEAD"]
      remote = origin
      merge = refs/heads/HEAD
[branch "Released_V1"]
      remote = origin
      merge = refs/heads/Released_V1
```

Eventhough it says not all refs have been pushed, I can't see any that have been

I've read a lot about user permissions being an issue but I'm the only person who is working on this project and both repos are on the same drive so what should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

When you cannot write to the .object folder you don't have enough rights. Like the message says.

```
unable to write sha1 filename
```

Here is the same Problem:

[git error “unable to write sha1 filename … Permission denied”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551441/git-error-unable-to-write-sha1-filename-permission-denied)

Comment: changing `sharedRepository = true` and `shareRepository = group` doesn't change anything. Pretty sure i'm a working on git 1.7.7.1